# jQuery Bookmarklet with $.post() or $.get()

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post, get

I've built a Bookmarklet based on Ben Almans jQuery enabled Bookmarklet.

The bookmarklet creates a  an fills it with some data from a `$.get('http://example.com/request/')` Request.

It works as long as I am on the same domain, but if I try to run it on another site, e.g. google the `$.get()` does not work.

I've also tried `$.getJSON()` and `$.post()`, but nothings seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax isn't cross-domain by default, so it'll only work within your domain.

However, you got some solutions. One is using curl with jquery ajax to get what you want, other is use a library like this one : http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this for [security related reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). An option would be to [turn your web server into a proxy](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html).

Comment: Thank you.
I am not sure, if works to turn my web server into a proxy.
Because if I run the Bookmarklet from another website than my own, the proxy is on another domain and will not work.
Am I right?

Comment: @Philipp yes that's right - the proxy has to be on the same domain